# Почему не могу об"null"ить переменную в цикле? Вроде тип Integer, но выдаёт ошибку " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: java, массивы, циклы, ссылки

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int c = 0; //Дабы цикл не был неиссякаемым
        int points = 0; //Дабы оценить себя по достоинству
        Integer [] field = new Integer[10]; //Сотворяем массив
        for (int i : field) {
            i = (int) (Math.random() * 2); //Забиваем по воле судьбы, числами от 0 до 1
        }
        do {
            System.out.println("Введите координату от 0 до 9"); //Определяем место во вселенной
            int a = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
            System.out.println("Введите предполагаемое значение от 0 до 1"); //Вводим значение присвоенное клетке
            int b = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
            if (field[a] == b) {
                System.out.println("Верно");
                points++; //Поощряем самодеятельность
            field[a] = null;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Неверно");
                points--; //Штрафуем за FakeNews
            }
            c++; 
        } while (c <= 9);
        System.out.println("Ваши очки" + points); //Подводим итоги существования
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Данный цикл

```
    Integer [] field = new Integer[10]; //Сотворяем массив
    for (int i : field) {
        i = (int) (Math.random() * 2); //Забиваем по воле судьбы, числами от 0 до 1
    }
```

не заполняет элементы массива `field` значениями. Он лишь присваивает значения переменной `i`, имеющий тип `int`, которая, к тому же, становится невидимой вне цикла.

Даже если вы исправите тип переменной `i` с типа int на `Integer` в заголовке цикла, как, например,

```
    Integer [] field = new Integer[10]; //Сотворяем массив
    for (Integer i : field) {
        i = (int) (Math.random() * 2); //Забиваем по воле судьбы, числами от 0 до 1
```

То этот цикл не меняет значения ссылок элементов массива. Он лишь поменяет значение ссылки `i` с `null` на ссылку на конкретный объект, а исходные ссылки элементов массива останутся без изменения и будут равны по-прежнему `null`.

Используйте цикл

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < field.length; i++ )
    {
        field[i] = ( int )( Math.random() * 2 );
    }
```

или

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < field.length; i++ )
    {
        field[i] = new Integer( ( int )( Math.random() * 2 ) );
    }
```